# Use Firebase SDK 3 with Ionic 1.X

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a chat in ionic 1.X and I wanted to use Firebase as my database and auth provider.First, I want to be able to create and login users using Firebase. I enabled in my account simple email and password authentication. However, most tutorials like this [one](http://www.joshmorony.com/email-and-facebook-authentication-with-ionic-and-firebase/) works with Firebase 2. If I follow it I have the next error:

And in my index.html I load firebase like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

And creating an user:

```
  $scope.signupEmail = function(){
    $scope.message = null;
    $scope.error = null;

    console.log('In signup email with username ' +  $scope.data.username + ' email ' + $scope.data.email + ' and password ' + $scope.data.password);
    var chatRef = new Firebase('https://some-url.firebaseio.com');
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(chatRef);
    auth.$createUser({
      email: $scope.data.email,
      password: $scope.data.password
    }).then(function(userData) {
        console.log("User created with uid: " + userData.uid);
        $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        $scope.error = error;
      });

  };
```

[image]

The logical conclusion and search google is that I should use Firebase 3 SDK to create an user. However, in the official Ionic documentation (not the legacy one) you find any section for integrating the new SDK with Ionic, if I go to index.html and add the new way to use firebase:

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
    var config = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
```

Then I'm not able to inject 'firebase' to my module.

[image]

**Any idea of how to integrate firebase sdk 3 and ionic 1.x?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using version 1.2.0 of **angularfire** - your `index.html` contains `.../angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js`.

That version does not support Firebase 3. However, there is a newer release of **angularfire** that does: [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

And there is a [migration guide](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md) that might make it easier to extrapolate the information in the tutorials you have found to Firebase 3.